# How to get information if someone redeem points?

Tags: python, twitch, twitch-api

tmi.twitch.tv does not support Channel Points what should I do? I couldn't find any other alternatives.

Comment: What do you want to get? The price, the name? Be more specific.

Comment: I need information if someone redeem points

Comment: Then could you please edit the question?

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to get information about a custom reward redemption

- Twitch EventSub, which offers a Webhook transport
- Twitch PubSub, which is not as useful and may get replaced by EventSub over sockets
- Twitch Chat, if the redemption has the user enter a chat message it's sent to chat, so this works for some but not all custom rewards

Of the three Twitch EventSub (over Webhooks) is the most effective.

The first step is to create a Web Accessable Server capable of recieving JSON via HTTP POST messages.

Once this have been created, and the logic put in place to handle validation and the steps to return the challenge then you move to the next step.

You tell Twitch has Topics you want to subscribe to, which for you will be `channel.channel_points_custom_reward_redemption.add`

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/eventsub/eventsub-subscription-types#channelchannel_points_custom_reward_redemptionadd

Describes the payload needed to be set to "Create EventSub Subscription" which is covered here https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#create-eventsub-subscription

You will need to have first obtained permission from the streamer you wish to collect events for, since this topic will require the `channel:read:redemptions` scope/permission from the streamer.

So you will also need an oAuth flow somewhere in order for the streamer to authenticate and grant access between your client and their Twitch account.

The complete workflow steps are described on https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/eventsub except for the oAuth authentication step for this topic.